# Is a mysql user defined function suitable for signing Amazon S3 url?

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-s3, user-defined-functions

I need to retrieve a result from a mysql database using a user defined function that recreates the following PHP code -

```
$signature = urlencode(base64_encode((hash_hmac("sha1", utf8_encode($string_to_sign), awsSecretKey, TRUE))));
```

Are UDF's up to the job? What are the security implications for storing the AWS secret key in the UDF / passing this as a variable?

Ideally I want to be able to do this -

```
$sql = "SELECT file_type, myPHPfunctionToSignFilename(file_name) ..."
$result = mysql_query($sql)
return ($result)
```

But I think myPHPfunctionToSignFilename needs to be MYSQL-UDF-FUNCTION...

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Stephen

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to do this in the database? Performance or some other reason? I don't think it'll matter in the former case.